# Argparse interaction with Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

So, for my assignment, I have to use argparse to parse in .cvs files and run calculation on them. I'm having an extremely hard time figuring out how to do this.

I've already made the three functions that are required, but I have no idea how to properly incorporate them into the skeleton code we were given.

See, when my program is tested, the run configs. are going to be edited with the appropriate parameters and designated .cvs file. The work that I've done so far was by hand-testing cvs files, rather than have them called / used appropriately using argparse. The work I've done doesn't even utilize argparse.

The only reason I have argparse in my code is because it was thrown at us with little to no explanation, and we have to interact with it to get the proper results. This is proving extremely difficult (and stressful) to me, so any push in the right direction is appreciated - I really want to understand the logic here.

The skeleton code we were given includes everything except my grand_total function, which I've left in as an example:

```
import argparse


def Grand_total(filepath):
  """
  Calculates the total amount of avocado sales given data from  a .csv file.
  """
  avo_price = open(filepath,"r")
  avo_price.readline() # to skip the header 
  lines_list=avo_price.readlines()
  sum = 0.0
  for line in lines_list:
    columns = line.split(",")
    prices= float(columns[2])
    volume = float(columns[3])
    total = (round((prices * volume),2))
    price_list = []
    price_list.append(total)
    for num in price_list:
      sum = sum + num
  print ("Total Sales:",(sum))



def parse_args():
    """
    parse_args takes no input and returns an Namespace dictionary describing the arguments selected
    by the user.  If invalid arguments are selected, the function will print an error message and quit.
    :return: Namespace with arguments to use
    """

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Read CSV input about avocados and print total amount sold")
    parser.add_argument('--input', '-i', dest='input', required=True, type=str,
                       help='input CSV file')

    parser.add_argument('--group_by_region', '-r', dest='group_by_region', action='store_true', default=False,
                       help='Calculate results per region (default: calculate for all regions)')
    parser.add_argument('--organic', '-o', dest='organic', action='store_true', default=False,
                       help='Only calculate for organic avocados (default: calculate for conventional and organic)')

    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    """
    The main body of the program.  It parses arguments, and performs calculations on a CSV
    """

    # get arguments entered by users
    args = parse_args()

    # TODO remove these print statements
    # This code is provided as an example for how to interpret the results of parse_args()
    print("Input file:      {}".format(args.Grand_total))
    print("Group by region: {}".format(args.city_total))
    print("Only organic:    {}".format(args.organic_total))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I run this (with the other functions included),
I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'Grand_total'
```

Answer (score 1):

What `argparse` does, among other things, is collect command line arguments into a `Namespace` object you can easily access. 
If all goes well, `args` would look something like this:

```
Namespace(input='my_csv.csv', group_by_region=False, organic=False)
```

You would then access, say, your input path, with `args.input`.

An example of how you could restructure your program:

```
def main():
    args = parse_args()  # Note: you don't actually need a separate function for this
    path = args.input
    if args.group_by_region:
        region_output = #  calculate for each region here
        # do something with region output

    else:
        Grand_total(path)
```

I actually did a quick project using `argparse` yesterday; you can take a look at it [here](https://github.com/marcuslimdw/pycogram/blob/master/run_pycogram.py); note that the arguments are stored in a [separate file](https://github.com/marcuslimdw/pycogram/blob/master/argument_spec.json).